# How to delete an item from array in Laravel Session?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I'm creating a cart system, this is my code to input some itens into the user Session:

```
public function jsonResponse($data){
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'users' => $data
    ]);
}

public function post(Request $request ,User $user)
{
    $request->session()->push('users', $user);
    return $this->jsonResponse($request->session()->get('users'));
}
```

How can I delete an unique item from the `users` array?

---

### Alternative 01

It's able to remove the item from the `users` array with the following code:

```
public function delete(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $users = $request->session()->get('users');

    foreach ($users as $key => $val) {
        if($user->id == $users[$key]->id){
            $array = $request->session()->pull('users', []);
            unset($array[$key]);
            $request->session()->put('users', $array);
            return $this->jsonResponse($request->session()->get('users'));
        }
    }

    return $this->jsonResponse($request->session()->get('users'));
}
```

But I was searching for a clean way... Without remove the array and put it back to the Session...

---

### Solution 01

The following alternative has been found for a cleaner code:

```
public function delete(Request $request, User $user)
{
    $users = $request->session()->get('users');

    foreach ($users as $key => $val) {
        if($user->id == $users[$key]->id){
            $request->session()->forget('users.'.$key);
            return $this->jsonResponse($request->session()->get('users'));
        }
    }

    return $this->jsonResponse($request->session()->get('users'));
}
```

Thanks to [Kyslik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1564365/kyslik) for remind the dot notation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`forget()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#deleting-data) or [`pull()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#storing-data) methods for that.

```
$request->session()->forget('key');
```

> The forget method will remove a piece of data from the session

```
$request->session()->pull('key', 'default');
```

> The pull method will retrieve and delete an item from the session in a single statement

Comment: But my `users` key is an array and I need to delete just a specific item from the array, not the entire array, with the `forget()` method I was just able to remove the entire array, or am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Then `pull()` it, make changes (by using `unset()`, for example) and then `push()` it back.

Comment: I already do that, but I was thinkig if there is a clear way... Look at my edit...

Comment: @CaioKawasaki I am not sure and can not check at the moment, but try using dot notation, `->forget('array.key');`

Comment: @Kyslik I had tried something like: `$request->session()->forget('users'.$key)`, but when I read your comment I went to see the code and recognized that I had let a detail pass, it worked like this: `$request->session()->forget('users.'.$key)`, nice =)